# how to use System.collections.generic to let users add their own words to a cmd project

Tags: c#, generics

Hi this time I'm trying to allow users to add their own words to a random sentence generator. at the moment it picks a random word from an array and substitutes it into a WriteLine statement and now I want to let users enter words that then go into the next generated sentence. Im told that I need to use System.collections.generic List(t) but am stuck on how to do so. This is my code so far...

```
using System;

namespace sentenceGenerator
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random ();

        Console.WriteLine ("****************************************");
        Console.WriteLine ("Welcome To The Random Sentence Generator");
        Console.WriteLine ("****************************************");
        Console.WriteLine ("Type " + "Exit" + " If You Wish To Exit The Program");
        Console.WriteLine ("*****************************************");
        Console.WriteLine ("Press Enter To Generate Another Random Sentence");
        Console.WriteLine ("***********************************************");

        do {

            string[] Nouns = new string [] // Nouns Array
        { "Dog", "Cat", "Snake", "Rhino", "Rat", "Horse", "Bear", "Lynx", "Octopus", "Skunk",     "Toucan", "Tortoise", "Donkey", "Tiger", "Lion", "Jaguar", "Duck", "Hamster", "Cow", "Sloth",     "Gecko" };
            string[] Verb = new string [] // Verbs Array
        { "licked", "killed", "fought", "ate", "swallowed", "stepped on", "squashed" };
            string[] Adjective = new string [] // Adjectives Array
            { "small", "cute", "big", "fat", "thin", "furry", "huge", "tiny" };
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("A " + Adjective [random.Next (0, Nouns.Length)] + Nouns     [random.Next (0, Nouns.Length)] + " " + Verb [random.Next (0, Verb.Length)] + " a " + Adjective     [random.Next (0, Nouns.Length)] + Nouns [random.Next (1, Nouns.Length)]); 
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------");

            // Exit Code
            string exit = Console.ReadLine();

            if (exit == "exit"){
                break;
            }
            //

        } while (true);




    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use `List<string>` instead of `string[]` and call `List<string>.Add()` to add a new string - have you read the documentation and examples or just flailing?

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` is a collection; just like an array. The advantage of a list is that it has a *variable number of elements*.

So instead of an array; declare a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> adjectives = new List<string> // Adjectives List
            { "small", "cute", "big", "fat", "thin", "furry", "huge", "tiny" };
```

And to add to it (from user input):

```
string userInputString = Console.ReadLine();
adjectives.Add(userInputString);
```

Finally, use `Count` instead of `Length` when determining the random max:

```
adjectives[random.Next(adjectives.Count)]
```

Comment: when using this i get an error "user input string does not exist in the current context

Comment: @anonymous Well yes, I made the variable up. You get user input from `Console.ReadLine`. I'll edit to make that clear.

Comment: thankyou bradley, I've done it now

Comment: @anonymous Great! To let you know about a feature of the site: You can mark the answer that helped you the best as "accepted" by clicking the green check mark next to it. Doing so gives you and the answerer some reputation, and lets the community know what helped you the most. Doing so is totally optional of course.

Answer (score 0):

Also reconsider how you are using Console.WriteLine:

```
Console.WriteLine("A " + Adjective [random.Next (0, Nouns.Length)] + Nouns     [random.Next (0, Nouns.Length)] + " " + Verb [random.Next (0, Verb.Length)] + " a " + Adjective     [random.Next (0, Nouns.Length)] + Nouns [random.Next (1, Nouns.Length)]);
```

Change to:

```
string adjective = Adjective [random.Next (0, Nouns.Length)];
...
Console.WriteLine( "A {0} {1} a {2}", adjective, verb, noun );
```